# XCGLogger does not colorise in debug window

Tags: xcglogger

The Github Readme mentions possibility of colours in debug. Despite configuration of the XcodeColors plugin, what else is needed to get colorised output there?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
log.xcodeColorsEnabled = true
```

when setting up your log object to explicitly turn on colours. Relying on the environment variable isn't great for iOS apps since you have to add it manually in your project. The environment variable works better for OS X apps since you can set it in your .profile etc and have it work for all projects.

Comment: Still it does not work. I cannot run the Demo shipped with it. Neither iOS or Mac OS.

Comment: And you have the XcodeColors plug-in installed? Note that plug-ins (including XcodeColors) do not work in Xcode 8.

Comment: No, I don't have that plugin. Do I have to?

Comment: Yes. The XcodeColors plug-in is what gives Xcode the ability to display colours in the console log. XCGLogger then includes the codes for XcodeColors to use.

Comment: ah, okey. Got it. From the doc, I thought it was some plugin that is supported, and not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS projects, the current version of Xcode (7.3) and XCGLogger (3.3) requires the following line as hinted at by Dave Wood:

```
log.xcodeColorsEnabled = true
```

You can put it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.swift after

```
let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()
log.setup(.Debug, showThreadName: true, showLogLevel: true, showFileNames: true, showLineNumbers: true, writeToFile: nil, fileLogLevel: nil)
```

and then test with

```
log.info("App started")
```